# index.php that requires ioncube loader will not run and produces an error message

Tags: php, ioncube

The error message: Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/boxbilling/install/index.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in Unknown on line 0

I don't know what any of this means, but would appreciate some guidance in finding the problem and fixing it.  Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that you have uploaded all files in the provided file.
Please also make sure that the index.php exists in install directory.